# Is it possible to browse the bundle/package file system on IOS device from a connected Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode

Some background: I have a data file in the bundle resources for my target. At startup my app tries to open it. This works on the iOS simulator but is not working on the actual iPod Touch device.

I would like to check that the file was correctly copied to the device. Is there anyway from the xcode organizer or something else to see what files are on the device?

I saw the question:
"Browse the files created on a device by the IOS application I'm developing, on workstation?"
The answer to that question describes how to download the application data (save game data etc) from the device back to the Mac but this doesn't appear to get the bundle data (the app itself and data files in the bundle).

Comment: I discovered that reason my file open was not working was case-sensitivity. The open call was using the filename "BIGFILE.000" while the file I put in the bundle was "bigfile.000". This works on the simulator because it is not case sensitive but the device is.

Comment: I observed some strange behavior though. I can fix this problem by changing the code to open "bigfile.000" but I tried to fix it the other way - by renaming the file to "BIGFILE.000". I could not get this to work. Despite removing the file from the bundle and the project, renaming in in the finder to uppercase and then re-adding it to the project and the bundle. It still copies it to the device as lower case. It shows up in the bundle with an upper case name (in the target's "Build Phases" tab under "Copy Bundle Resources).

Comment: When I run the app in Xcode 4 there is an obscure way to see what it is copying to the device. There is a rectangular status area in the top center of the main window. As it copies the files a small dark grey circle with a number (3 or 2) appears in the left of this area. If you click on that it pops up a window saying what file it is copying at the time with a progress bar. In that display it says it is copying the lower case file name.

Comment: I eventually discovered that because I had a file named "bigfile.000" in the bundle on the device it always uses that case even though the file it was copying from on the Mac was uppercase. Using the xcode organizer to delete the application from the device fixed that issue.